# Add only a div dynamicly with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the code below to add a div under an image, but the problem is if i have more than one image the script adds the div below each image.. So i want only add one div bellow of the first image.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".gdl-blog-full").find("img:first-child").after("<div id='1' style='width:400px; margin-top:10px; background-color: #000;'> You are watching 5th object out of 100 </div>");
});
</script>
```

And the code of the body:

```
<div class="gdl-blog-full">
<img src="1.jpg" width="675" height="383" />

<p>
<img src="2.jpg" width="479" height="246" /> </p>
</div>
```

Thank you all..

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/nKTYK/)

Comment: `:first-child` doesn't work because the second image is the first child of `<p>`, so it matches the selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use the [**:first**](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector instead, like `$(".gdl-blog-full").find("img:first")`

In your code all images are first child of `div.gdl-blog-full`, so you can use `.first()` or the selector `:first`

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2bRVN/)**

Answer (score 2):

You're so close, just change `:first-child` to `:first`

```
$(".gdl-blog-full").find("img:first-child").after("<div id='1' style='width:400px; margin-top:10px; background-color: #000;'> You are watching 5th object out of 100 </div>");
------------------------------^_________^
```

change to

```
$(".gdl-blog-full").find("img:first").after("<div id='1' style='width:400px; margin-top:10px; background-color: #000;'> You are watching 5th object out of 100 </div>");
------------------------------^___^
```